# What is the optimal solution for this problem?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

There are two players in a game. There are N rods and the players take their turn alternatively with player A going first.
in each turn-
player remove one rod from the sack (of length x)  and adds this length to his sum (initially there sum is zero) ,also if the length of rod is not one then the player cuts the rod into half and puts it back inside the sack
Game ends when a player is not able to take his turn i.e. no rods are left in the sack. Both players want to maximize their sum.
What is the maximum sum Player A (who is going first) gets if both players play optimally.

consider when the player cuts the rod into half, and if the length of rod is odd then player will cuts it into smallest positive integer that is less than length. For example - if length of rod is 7 the player will cut it into length of 3. and put the rod of length 3 inside sack

Comment: When a rod is cut in half, are *both* halves put back, or just one of them?

Comment: just one of them

Comment: A greedy solution should be sufficient